# Google data studio connector: "Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request."

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm not sure where to look to get information on what error Google Data Studio is encountering when running a custom Google App Script connector.

I created a script, published as a manifest with a new version and copied the ID.

In Data Studio I open the edit, open the new connector page, and in developer enter the ID, which brings up my app script and asks me to authorize access to an external resource (assumed this is because it's querying a not-Google website).

The connector page displays my schema labels. I fill in some information, and click on "Connect", and a box pops up: "Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request", along with an Error ID.

Where do I find the information behind that ID? I've found the script executions page with functions that were run, but they all look like they successfully run (no failures).

Nothing is getting logged in the log viewer or Stackdriver logs.

I don't know how to test it within the script editor because Data Studio is supposed to make calls to functions with a request object, and in the editor attempts to test functions requiring that object fail because it's undefined.

Is there a place to view more of what triggered the error? Or something I can insert that will get logged to Logger.log from Data Studio execution attempts properly?

EDIT: Okay, looks like console.log() will send messages to the stackdriver log, but I'm still not finding errors or what exactly Data Studio is having issues with. I added a log message to the beginning to each function to say they are about to run, and the logs viewer shows, of the required functions for Data Studio, getAuthType(), isAuthValid(), getConfig(), isAdminUser(), and getSchema is run and nothing else...

I'm still searching for a log from the lambda engine (or Data Studio) to tell me what exactly it doesn't like when trying to run.

Comment: If your `isAdminUser()` returns `true`, you should see a stack trace with the error message (given the error is due to your connector code).

Comment: Is the stack trace supposed to be in the popup with the original error, or is it in a separate log somewhere?

Comment: It should be in the pop-up.